# Super key in SQL server as foreign key

Tags: mysql, model, conceptual

I have to trasnfer data model from the pic below to SQL database. I have a problem with understanding one element. As you can see, Super_ssn of Employee points to SSN. Does it mean that these two attributes are SUPER KEY? If yes, then if we take under consideration relation between for example Dependent that holds FOREIGN KEY of Employee, then does the FOREIGN KEY consists of SSN, and Super_Ssn as SUPER KEY or only consists of SSN ?

[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSPJj.png)

Comment: Looks like `super_ssn` is the SSN of the employee's supervisor. So if my supervisors SSN is 1, my employee record would have 1 in the `super_ssn` column and he would have 1 in the `ssn` column. `super_ssn` is a foreign key that references `ssn`.

Comment: Ohh i get it. Thank you!